# C++ STL: Passing an empty container to lower_bound

Tags: c++, stl, containers, stl-algorithm

Is the behavior for passing an empty container to `std::lower_bound` defined?

I checked cppreference.com and an old version of the C++ standard that I found online, but couldn't find a definite answer.

The [cppreference.com documentation for `std::deque::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) has a sentence

> The iterator first does not need to be dereferenceable if `first==last`: erasing an empty range is a no-op.

I miss something like this for `std::lower_bound` and other algorithms.

Comment: You don't pass **containers** to `std::lower_bound`; you pass **ranges**, in the form of pairs of iterators. Containers are a common way of managing ranges, but they are not the only way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) on the return value of `std::lower_bound(first, last)`:

> "[it returns] *Iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than value, **or `last` if no such element is found**.*".

*(emphasis mine)*

In an empty range, there will be no elements that satisfy the criteria, so `last` will be returned.

Concluding from this, applying `std::lower_bound` (and similar) on the empty range is *well-defined*. It does nothing and returns `last`, which is equal to `first`.

Answer (score 4):

The [Standard says](http://eel.is/c++draft/lower.bound):

> *Returns:* The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first, last]` such that for every iterator `j` in the range `[first, i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: `*j < value` or `comp(*j, value) != false`.

Now:

1. The range `[first, last]` for an empty container has a single member, namely the iterator returned by its member function `end()`.
2. `i` can therefore by only `end()`.
3. There is only one viable range `[first, i)`, which is `[end, end())`.
4. This range is empty, since there is no element that is *greater or equal* than `end()` and *lower* then `end()` at the same time.

Since there is no *every iterator `j`*, I guess the quoted sentence can be rewritten into:

*Returns:* The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first, last]`.

Which implies that the only `i` that can be returned is `end()`.

Answer (score 2):

std::lower_bound answers the question, “Where (as in, just before what iterator value) is the first place that the given element can be inserted without violating the ordering?” If the [*first, last*) range given is empty, the only place to insert anything is just before *last* (equal to *first*), so that’s what *lower_bound* returns.